# How do I update my React app with new props after an AJAX call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs

I have a React-Rails app, in which some results data is handed to the app initially and is then displayed via props in a ResultsTable.

However, after I search the data for a keyword, I'm not sure the best practice for then displaying the new results data.

In short, do I need to create a property on the state object for results, so that then I set the state with the new data in the AJAX success function (i.e., this.setState({results: data})?

Or is there a way to update the app with the new data without putting the results on the state object? I'm trying to minimize my use of state.

Below is the primary component:

```
class ResultsApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {keyword: ''};
  }
  fetchData() {
     $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/results/',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      data: this.state,
    }).done((data, textStatus, jqXHR) => {
      // what is the best practice to include here?
    });
  }
  handleKeywordChange (keyword) {
    this.setState({keyword: keyword}, () => this.fetchData());
  } 
  render () {
   return <div>
     <KeywordSearch keyword={this.state.keyword} handleKeywordChange={this.handleKeywordChange}/>
     <ResultsTable results={this.props.results}/>
    </div>;
  }   
}
```

Below is the search component:

```
class KeywordSearch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleKeywordChange = this.handleKeywordChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleKeywordChange (e) {
    this.props.handleKeywordChange(e.target.value);
  }
  render () {
    return <input 
                type="text"
                name="keyword"
                value={this.props.keyword}
                onChange={this.handleKeywordChange}
            />
  }
}
```

Below is the results table:

```
class ResultsTable extends React.Component {
 constructor (props) {
    super(props);
 }
 render () {
   const resultsRows = this.props.results.map((result) => {
            return (<ResultRow result={results} />);
        });
   return {resultsRows};
 }
}
```

The ResultRow component simply parses and displays the data contained in each result.

Below is the results controller, which uses a keyword_search method on the Result model:

```
class ResultsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @results = Result.limit(10)
    @results = Result.keyword_search(params[:keyword]) if params[:keyword].present?
  end

 # rest of code

end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do components that accept stuff as props instead of handling state themselves. The top component can handle state while the bottom component can be dumb, they just render props.

```
class ClassDetails{
  render = () => {
    if(this.state.students && this.state.room)
      return <ClassDisplay 
        students={this.state.students} room={this.state.room} onEdit={this.handleEdit}
      />
    else
      return "please wait"
  }
}
```

This way, your inner components can be stateless and "do less": not have too much logic inside them.